# Linux kernel module making a proc entry does not print on reading the proc entry to user

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

In the book *Operating System Concepts: 10th edition*, there's a programming project to log some information about a process by providing its pid `echo`'d to the `/proc` entry made while initializing the module, namely here, `/proc/pid`.

```c
/**
 * This function is called each time the /proc/pid is read.
 * 
 * This function is called repeatedly until it returns 0, so
 * there must be logic that ensures it ultimately returns 0
 * once it has collected the data that is to go into the 
 * corresponding /proc file.
 */
static ssize_t proc_read(struct file *file, char __user *usr_buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
        int rv = 0;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        static int completed = 0;
        struct task_struct *tsk = NULL;

        if (completed) {
                completed = 0;
                return 0;
        }

        /* l_pid is a global that gets set properly when the proc entry is read. */
        tsk = pid_task(find_vpid(l_pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
        
        if (tsk == NULL) {
            rv = -1;
            return rv;
        }

        completed = 1;
        rv = sprintf(buffer, "pid = [%d], command = [%s], state = [%ld]\n", 
                    tsk->pid, tsk->comm, tsk->state);

        if (copy_to_user(usr_buf, buffer, rv)) {
                rv = -1;
        }
        
        return rv;
}
```

My problem is with the `proc_read` function. The way I understand it (as explained in the book) is that `rv` has to be 0 eventually because the function specified as the `.read` field in the `file_operations` struct keeps getting called till returning 0.

The problem is that I do not understand the necessity of having all this "complete" logic. If I change the code to be like this:

```c
static ssize_t proc_read(struct file *file, char __user *usr_buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
        int rv = 0;
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        struct task_struct *tsk = NULL;

        /* l_pid is a global that gets set properly when the proc entry is read. */
        tsk = pid_task(find_vpid(l_pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
        
        if (tsk == NULL) {
            rv = -1;
            return rv;
        }

        int num_bytes = sprintf(buffer, "pid = [%d], command = [%s], state = [%ld]\n", 
                    tsk->pid, tsk->comm, tsk->state);

        if (copy_to_user(usr_buf, buffer, num_bytes)) {
                rv = -1;
        }
        
        return rv;
}
```

To my understanding, when the proc entry is read, this function will get called, either returning -1 (if `tsk == NULL` or could not copy from `buffer` to `usr_buf`) *and thus get called again*. Or it will return 0 on success.

The problem with this change (of course) is that it does not work. It does not print anything to the console when issuing `cat /proc/pid`. However, by `printk`ing the string inside `buffer`, it appears to be correct (at least in the *kernel log buffer*).

Comment: Is this function a part of existing kernel code, or a new one that you're making. If new, then you'll have to hook it into existing code somehow (register new procfs entry, for example), it won't get called automatically.

Comment: I just omitted everything else and left the problematic function. The first code works as intended. The second does not. Both are running in a (presumably) correct environment of creating a procfs entry, writing to the entry triggers a function that stores what have been written to a global variable (l_pid).  Afterwards, the `proc_read` function is invoked when the procfs entry,`/proc/pid/`, is interrogated.

Comment: Do you know of `strace`? It might be helpful to you in future. Anyway, the problem is that `cat` calls `read`, which can return: `number of bytes that were read`, `0` for end of file or negative error code. Since you never return a positive value from `proc_read`, cat doesn't know any data was put into returned buffer.

Comment: And to be complete ... this is normally implemented with a seq_file, so you don't need the awkward file position handling. Search Linux kernel for usage of `proc_create` for examples.